# Azure File Storage Error: Condition Headers Are Not Supported

Tags: azure-storage

When attempting to download a PDF file to a browser directly from Azure File Storage I get this error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>ConditionHeadersNotSupported</Code>
        <Message>
            Condition headers are not supported. RequestId:a84ee68e-   001a-001b-4223-bff5e7000000 Time:2017-04-27T06:57:22.2002199Z
        </Message>
</Error>
```

Edge:  Blank page or blank page with frozen loading indicator.

FireFox:  Second time, shows dialog to download file.

Chrome:  Blank page or When PDF Documents “Open PDF files in default PDF viewer application” setting is checked, shows dialog to download file.

IE:  Shows dialog to download file.

Safari:  Displays PDF.

The behavior can be seen here:
    https://peachstatepca.file.core.windows.net/content/newsletters/PresseApril2017.pdf?sv=2016-05-31&sr=f&sig=rkQEmY6IWXZqcgvhmm00gLQ%2FCZEq6nsH95S3aP9T72A%3D&se=2017-05-01T11:46:18Z&sp=r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure File Storage Error: Condition Headers Are Not Supported

<del>Since the new Edge browser will not have any support for ActiveX plug-ins. Therefore, Acrobat/Reader plug-in won't work with Edge. We can get more details for [Change in support for Acrobat and Reader plug-ins in modern web browsers](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/change-in-support-for-acrobat-and-reader-plug-ins-in-modern-web-.html) and [Microsoft Edge: Building a safer browser](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/11/microsoft-edge-building-a-safer-browser/#5yeZAdSxQX1eI0rW.97).</del>

**Edit:**

If we try to download the PDF file with Edge in the private and develop mode, we can get the error message "**Something’s keeping this PDF from opening**" and also can know that edge browser has sent 2 requests. And second request with Header '`If-range`'. According the Azure file storage [Get File API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file), there is no specifying Conditional Headers `If-Range` supported. I also find a similar [issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7045462/) about edge browser.

[image]

I also test in the Firefox and Chrome, then just get the 1 request.

[image]

Note： For Azure Blob Service, the pdf file can be opened correctly from the edge browser. As Blob [Get Blob API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) that supports a successful operation to read the full blob returns status code 200 (OK) and
a successful operation to read a specified range returns status code 206 (Partial Content).

Comment: I really think that the issue is with Azure File Storage, not the browser. When PDF files are loaded from the web site file system, they display just fine in all of the browsers. Edge has built-in support for displaying PDF files and does not need a plug-in.  Actually, it can be set as the default PDF reader in Windows 10, in that case, there is no need for Acrobat.

Comment: I am going to switch to Azure Blob Storage.  Everything works fine with that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please vote on this issue to get it escalated and corrected at the service-side.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/37496332-ignore-conditional-headers-on-file-storage-request

Answer (score 7):

We were also facing this issue and the easiest way, till Azure File Team implements the suggestion given in the [Azure Feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/37496332-ignore-conditional-headers-on-file-storage-request), a workaround is to append extra parameter at the end of URL.
So, for the above URL -- 
https://peachstatepca.file.core.windows.net/content/newsletters/PresseApril2017.pdf?sv=2016-05-31&sr=f&sig=rkQEmY6IWXZqcgvhmm00gLQ%2FCZEq6nsH95S3aP9T72A%3D&se=2017-05-01T11:46:18Z&sp=r***&xyz=timestamp of client***

This will ensure browser is not caching and hence conditional headers will not be added

Answer (score 4):

There is noting wrong or any issue with Azure file storage, its because of some proxy/cache server. You can use following solution.

```
/// token = SharedAccessSignature
    string tick = $"&{ DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Ticks}";
    Uri url = new Uri(file.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + token + tick);
```

Comment: This will completely eliminate the caching which is not good. Every time the page loads all the images will load again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# and the Nuget packages then you can do this programatically like so

```
var sas = fileRef.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1))
},
new SharedAccessFileHeaders()
{
    CacheControl = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure File storage doesn't support Conditional Headers at this time.

A [workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#error-conditionheadersnotsupported-from-a-web-application-using-azure-files-from-browser) is to use the `CacheControl` property and set it to `no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`.

- You can do this for new files during upload by setting the Properties
  of the File.
- For existing files, they can be updated via a Powershell script, or one by one using Storage Explorer. You'll need to clear your browser cache to remove existing cached header information.

[image: Using Storage Explorer to set CacheControl property]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the CORS rule for your share

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services

or you might have uploaded an empty file.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.