# azure file storage does not seem to work "without code changes" as Microsoft claims

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I have been working for a while on lifting and shifting an app to use Azure File Storage since MS claims [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/) that you can migrate without changing code. However, in practice it does not seem to be that easy. I tried mounting file storage as a drive letter, but I found out that while a user can do that manually on their computer, the web app does not have access to do that operation.  So I wound up using their [cloud apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files), which seem to work okay but its taken several days and a fair amount of testing to upgrade our existing application to use this.

Another issue we had was that in order to provide urls, we had to create a [SAS or shared access signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1), which does provide extra security, but is also more code changes to add it everywhere the app needs to provide links to the end users. I also had another issue with links not working, that may have been related to a caching issue and seemed to be fixed now with [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706605/azure-file-storage-error-condition-headers-are-not-supported#answer-44155854).

I want to believe their claim that you can migrate without changing code, just change your config value to point to new folder locations or something, but my experience has been that this is either an outright lie or making it work without changing code, required so much technical digging that it was not worth the effort of continuing down that road.

So my question to any Azure guru or anyone out there, how can Azure possibly claim that you can "Migrate without changing code"???  That seems to be a lie, gives unexpected challenges and sets unrealistic expectations with the client.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I once followed [this guide](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/map-network-drive-to-azure-storage-account-file-storage/) a long while ago and it worked like charm. I did not have to change any code in my app.

Comment: If you had used Virtual Machines instead of App Service, then it would have been possible for you to migrate your application without making any code changes. Comparing On-Prem VM/Physical Box to Azure App Service is not a fair comparison IMHO.

Comment: Web Apps don't allow you to attach a File Storage disk (this has been answered elsewhere as well). You *can* attach a File share to a VM. Also, you have local, durable storage in Web Apps, shared across instances of your web app, that you can consider using. Honestly, no need ranting and saying someone is telling you a lie - there's no lie here.

Comment: Good points. Perhaps its not a lie, but I think there should be several disclaimers or asterisks on the 'no code changes needed' assertion. I guess that is meant for VMs, which in the cloud and SaaS world, my mindset was that IaaS to be avoided whenver possible because of all of the benefits you can get with PaaS or SaaS offerings. I guess I took the harder road by pushing for PaaS really hard, but in the end I think that is worth it.

Comment: And David, I recognize that there is 50gb of local storage but this legacy app is at 400gb and growing for its storage needs (all images, pdfs, etc) stored locally, so that is not an option for me either. Thanks for all of the comments!

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's claim that "it's simple lift and shift migration" (which is generally understood to be lifting the physical vm and replacing it with a virtual machine) is correct. If you had just done that, it would be easy. But you wouldn't be taking advantage of PaaS benefits.

Lift and Shift traditionally meant to physically relocate the required infrastructure to a different location. Often it would be as a company ran out of space in their own building, they would lift and shift the racks, routers and servers into a new datacenter that had space.

With a cloud model though, you can't physically lift them into a virtual space, so the intention is to replace like for like where you possibly can. ie - replace all servers with similar virtual machines.

What you've undertaken is a cloud application modernisation effort, or a re-architecture. That ***does*** require more work and requires a deeper understanding of the platform and code changes, but also reaps greater benefits. [TechTarget have a simple article on the benefits of both.](http://searchcloudcomputing.techtarget.com/feature/When-to-adopt-the-lift-and-shift-cloud-migration-model) Calling it a lie because you misunderstood what lift and shift means is a bit rough.

General rule of thumb when doing any sort of migration - make as few changes as possible. So in your case, a pure lift and shift first. Get it stable. Then do the cloud modernisation effort.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I wasn't aware of the differentiation. I probably could have just started with doing PaaS for the database since that is often minimal changes and throw the rest in a VM and tackle that later, but I felt that the benefits were worth it and I did not know the depth of all of the pitfalls at the time.

Comment: Yeah - that's why a lift and shift is so popular, particularly with large enterprises. It avoids the pitfalls, but allows them to scale/de-scale, move capex to opex etc. More benefits can be gained by moving to PaaS, and even more to SaaS. It really depends on the use case.