# Azure File Storage the server responded with a status of 400 (Condition headers are not supported.)

Tags: azure-storage, azure-files

I have some png files stored in Azure file Storage, and I'm retrieving and displaying it from my MVC web project to the browser. But sometimes I get the below error message from browser console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Condition headers are not supported.)

If I refresh the page again, the error message disappears automatically. But it doesn't solve my problem as I run my MVC project again, the same error comes back.  How to solve it?

Comment: It would be better if you can provide the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's acutally a common issue on Azure Storage, which be listed in the offical reference [`Common REST API Error Codes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/common-rest-api-error-codes) as the figure below.

[image]

It means that [Get File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file) REST API does not support those request headers which not be listed in the [`Request Headers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-file#request-headers).

[image]

There is a similar SO thread [Azure File Storage Error: Condition Headers Are Not Supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706605/azure-file-storage-error-condition-headers-are-not-supported), which got the same issue with yours. It seems to show up different behavior in different browses when you get a file from Azure File Storage.

I could not reproduce this issus by a file url with SAS token, but I really recommend that you need to store these static files like images on Azure Blob Storage, as I known and as Azure best practice, to show an image by its url with sas token or a public container.