# Append querystring to img tags within a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string like so:

```
<p>1</p><p><img src="https://somesite/1.png?x=1&y=2"></p>
<p>2</p><p><img src="https://somesite/2.png?x=1&y=2"></p>
<p>3</p><p><img src="https://somesite/3.png?x=1&y=2"></p>
```

It is the result of [Kendo UI's editor](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/editor/).

I would like all image src's to be appended with a tick something like &tick=2342342343 (because I'm trying to overcome a caching issue like [this one from another stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56704715/6639596))

So that the output would look like this:

```
<p>1</p><p><img src="https://somesite/1.png?x=1&y=2&tick=2342342343"></p> 
<p>2</p><p><img src="https://somesite/2.png?x=1&y=2&tick=2342342343"></p>
<p>3</p><p><img src="https://somesite/3.png?x=1&y=2&tick=2342342343"></p>
```

I think reg expression might be a good start:

```
var img = "img";
var imgRegExp = "<img src=\"[^\"]*\">";
Regex re = new Regex(imgRegExp);    
if (editorText!=null && editorText.Contains(img))
{
    //replace each editorText
}
```

Comment: HTML is not regular,  it's a dedicated specification, use a dedicated HTML parser for the best results

Comment: 0011, Is right, if your input is not exactly what you are showing You will just butcher your HTML.

Comment: You can only use regex with your data if you have full control of how the data is generated (like by some tools that generated only specific HTML fragments). At any rate, your current regex only matches `img` elements with a single `src` attribute, this is not replacing you are talking about. What did you try to actually achieve the result you are after?

Comment: Thank you I will attempt to use an HTML parser and reply with the answer

Comment: The string comes from Kendo UI's Editor and is not a HTML doc per say. Would I still use a html parser? If so what would be a good one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I join the comments saying that a the HTML may change and a regex might suddenly not work anymore if the HTML output changes. But sometimes a regex is far more efficient than loading a complete parser. So it depends on the risk of changes and if it's the case, do you have control on these changes? (updates of Kendo UI, etc)

For a regex solution, why not having a go with this: https://regex101.com/r/nJ3CL8/1

You can generate the code directly from the regex101 saved example.

My thoughts for a quick solution:

- I keep in mind that some spaces can be all around. Yes, even around the `=` sign!
- Use case insensitive flag as it could be `<IMG Src="..." />`
- They can be any type of other attribute between `img` and `src` so capture it too.
- An attribute can be surounded by single or double quotes, and even nothing! I didn't take in consideration this case as it's usually not the case, typically for a `src` attribute.

The pattern and the substitution strings would be this in C#:

```cs
string pattern = @"<\s*img\s*([^>]*?)src\s*=\s*([""'])(.*?)\2";

string substitution = @"<img \1src=\2\3&tick=123456789\2";
```

Explanation:

- `\s*` means any spaces, 0 or multiple times.
- `[^>]*?` means any char except `>` 0 or more times, but ungreedy (not searching to far).
- `([^>]*?)` is to capture these attributes before the *src* attribute. It's capture n°1 => `\1` in replacement pattern.
- `(["'])` is to capture the single or double quote. It's capture n°2 => re-used later.
- `(.*?)` captures the *src* value in ungreedy way. It only works because I used the `\2` backreference of the single/double quote.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I opted for regex. The HTML parsing wasn't working out as @Wiktor-Stribiżew pointed out - I'm using an editor to generate the few tags.

```
private static void AppendQueryStringToIMG()
    {
        string output = "<p>1</p><p><img src=\"https://a_dynamic_environment.file.core.windows.net/some-proj/my-images/img__1.png?x=123&y=234\"></p><p>2</p><p><img src=\"https://a_dynamic_environment.file.core.windows.net/some-proj/my-images/img__2.png?x=123&y=234\"></p><p>3</p><p><img src=\"https://a_dynamic_environment.file.core.windows.net/some-proj/my-images/img__3.png?x=123&y=234\"></p>";
        
        if (output != null && output.Contains("img"))
        {
            var m = Regex.Match(output, "<img .*?src=\\\"(.*?)\\\"");

            while (m.Success)
            {
                var href = m.Groups[1].Value;
                output = output.Replace(href, href + "&ticks=" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Ticks);

                m = m.NextMatch();
            }
        }

        //output:
        //string with &tick=1231231231 at the end of each img
    }
```

Comment: Well done :-) I've just given you a more complete solution, a bit safer than yours.